# One-to-One Relation or Use the Same Table?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, one-to-one

I have the following tables created:

Animes(id,title,date), Comics(id,title,date), TVSeries(id,title,season,episode,date)

Some of them have already foreign keys (for one-to-many or many-to-many relations) of directors, genres, articles and so on.

Now i would like to create two more tables Reviews(id,rating,date) and Posts(id,thumbid,articleid,reviewid).
A review is about one Anime and/or Comic TVSerie and vise-versa but properties of a review may be in more than one table. Its the same about a posts.

Is this a typical example of one-to-one relation in separate table or is it more efficient to add more properties to the existing tables?
So more tables and relations or less tables more columns?

Thank you and i hope my question isnt that stupid but im a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your requirements are, but the choices are as follows:

1. Have Reviews have 2 columns, either being a foreign key to the applicable table, can be NULL. This is really for when a single review can be about both.
2. Have a ReviewsComics and ReviewsAnime table. You'd then have all the fields from Reviews in each table (and no Reviews table).
3. An alternative (2) is to use them in conjunction with a Reviews table, then those 2 tables only has 2 fields which are foreign keys to Reviews and Comics/Anime respectively (thus no direct link between Reviews and Comics/Anime).
4. Have a base table to which Anime and Comics are linked to 1-to-1 and have reviews link to that table instead.
5. (Edit) If all the fields are all going to be the same (or similar) for Anime/Comics, you can merge them into a single table and add a type field, indicating Anime/Comics, then the problem goes away. This is similar to the base table option.

EDIT: The 2 reviews tables will probably give the best performance (unless you want to select all reviews for either, often), but with proper indices the performance shouldn't be an issue with any of the above.

Comment: let me pick up a pencil and a piece of paper and try to understand what you explaining me. Thank you

Comment: 1st. You mean 2 MORE columns right? Otherwise it doesnt make sense. 2nd. This is like: add more properties to the existing tables option,  right? Having Anime table and insert columns with properties of reviews, posts etc. 3rd. This is more like many to many relation. Is that useful in this situation? 4th. Why to do that? I dont need Anime-Comics-TVseries direct relation, *(i think).

Comment: @fat_mike (1) Yes, 2 more columns. (2) will have the following: ReviewsComics, ReviewsAnime, Comics, Anime. (3) will have the same as 2, but also Reviews (and ReviewsComics, ReviewsAnime will only have fields to link the Reviews and Comics/Anime tables). (4) allows you to have Reviews pointing to TVSeries and Comics and Anime pointing there too so you don't really have to worry about linking Reviews and Comics/Anime directly (so have TVSeries FKs in Reviews, Comics and Anime). They are all viable and there are minor advantages and disadvantages to each.

Comment: @fat_mike If you're planning on having as many as 15 different things that can be reviewed (as you mentioned in one of your comments), I'd definitely suggest (4) from my answer. It's probably the slowest of the solutions, but it's the cleanest (no empty data and few tables) and the performance hit isn't really much to worry about with proper indexing. If, however, the fields are all going to be the same, you can just use the base table and add a type field to the base table, indicating Anime/Comics (As (5) (added)).

Comment: 5th option seems the best as the fields will be almost identical but a lot of releases have the same title in Comics/Anime so type field has to have more that one entries separated by a comma, which isn't usually correct. Is it?

Comment: My thoughts would be to have 2 rows - (id=1, title=someTitle, date=someDate, type=Anime), (id=2, title=someTitle, date=someDate, type=Comics), unless you want a review to be marked as for both, then we're back to (4) again (and, in that case, nothing else, except (1), would work). Note that having multiple rows could become a problem if you start adding many more fields (but, as an example, different categories of the same title tend to be released on different dates, so 2 rows could be better, or (4) again, since you could have some info in the base table, and some in the given category).

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will go with option #4 and start testing while programming.

Answer (score 2):

In my view, It is better to avoid foreign key relationship for one-to-one relationship. It is best suitable for one - many relationships.

Comment: so you recommend to add the review properties in the existing tables? So for example Comics will be like (id, title, date, rating, reviewdate) and TVSeries(id, title, season, episode, date, rating, reviewdate) and so on..

Comment: yes..! It boosts the performance also...when compared with multiple tables. The more tables you create the more joins you need to write.I think I justified it well.Vote up if you agree with my answer.

Comment: i dont know if i agree because as i said im confused. Well its a personal project so it will continuously upgraded and before start programming i would like to have the more efficient and expandable database i can create. Because for example in reviews and/or posts or any other table, i might add more properties in the future. So a table of 14-15 columns isnt gonna be too "heavy"? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If it such a small number of rows it is not a matter, go for whichever you feel comfortable. multiple tables are also fine.

Comment: i meant columns not rows. Edited when you probably answering.

Comment: No problem mike.. you can use such multiple tables if they are smaller tables which handles lesser amounts of data, does not matter about columns. But if it is handling with large amounts of data better avoid it.But if you use single table It would be very simple to write the queries even. Just think about it.

Comment: One-to-one relationship foreign keys are useful to prevent columns having empty values, there are databases where using this is the best option, as otherwise your storage will just skyrocket.